# Is it ok to keep a refference to Resources object in android as a class field?

Tags: android

Is it ok to have a class field like this:

```
private Resources resources;
```

And set it in the constructor like this:

```
resources = myViewGroup.getContext().getResources();
```

I have never saw such a reference so I'm afraid there is a danger here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not dangerous, but it seems like not very elegant;

From docs:

```
 The Android SDK tools compile your application's resources into the application binary at build time.
```

It means that they won't change during Runtime, so any reference to them you keep will always be up-to-date.  Because of the same reason, and the  [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) I wouldn't advice to pass the reference to `Resources` but rather pick them up at some high level (where you have access to `Context`, in eg. `Activity`) and pass the values to functions as `String`, `Drawable`, `float` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the code as it is.

Potential danger is that it would point to the wrong resources or cause memory leaks.

When the configuration changes e.g. because of screen rotation, by default Android destroys your activity and recreates it with updated configuration-specific resources.

Since you have it as a regular member variable and not as a static class variable, the reference is held only as long as the object itself is alive. No leak and since you update the reference in constructor, it will point to the correct resource variant as well.

If you implemented custom configuration change handling with `configChanges` in manifest, the default destroy-and-recreate config change handling does not apply. In those cases you might accidentally retain references to old `Resources` object.